# perl script for find and replace or insert if blank

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a perl script to search a config file for the following line:

```
 remote_phonebook.data.1.url =
```

and do 1 of 2 things:

1. if the right of side of the = is blank add someString
2. if there is something there, replace anything there with someString

This will insert just fine:

```
s/remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.url = /remote_phonebook.data.1.url = someString/;
```

however if someString already exists, it will append it to look like this:

```
remote_phonebook.data.1.url = someString someString
```

This will replace just fine if someString already exists, but wont insert if its blank.

```
s/remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.url = someString/remote_phonebook.data.1.url = someString/;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is your friend, here. It means "match 0 or more (`*`) of any character (`.`)":

```
s/remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.url =.*/remote_phonebook.data.1.url = someString/;
```

So whether or not there is *anything* after the `=`, you'll end up with the contents you want.  To make sure that you're matching from the *start* of the line (so "xxxremote_phonebook..." won't match), and to allow for more (or less) space before the "=", I'd use:

```
s/^remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.url\s*=.*/remote_phonebook.data.1.url = someString/;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s/^\s*remote_phonebook\.data\.1\.url\s*=\K.*/someString/;
```

The `.*` will match anything up to a newline.
The `\K` makes it so you don't have to repeat everything.